# Multi Row, Multi Column Button Group in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, button, buttongroup

How can I create a multi row (2) and multi column (3) button group of 6 buttons in Jquery Mobile? The Buttons need to be connected and have to have the same size.
Here is a sketch:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two three item [navbar](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html)s do the trick:

```
<div style="margin:20px">
  <div data-role='navbar'>
    <ul>
      <li><button>A</button></li>
      <li><button>B</button></li>
      <li><button>C</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div data-role='navbar'>
    <ul>
      <li><button>D</button></li>
      <li><button>E</button></li>
      <li><button>F</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```